# Почему gulp не собирает dist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp

Вот gulpfile

```
    /*------------------------------------*\
        #require
\*------------------------------------*/

var gulp       = require('gulp'),

        msts       = require('gulp-minify-css'),
        sass       = require('gulp-sass'),
        prsts      = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),

        msct       = require('gulp-uglify'),
        browserify = require('browserify'),
        reactify   = require('reactify'),

        rimraf     = require('rimraf'),
        rename     = require('gulp-rename'),
        watch      = require('gulp-watch'),

        brsync     = require('browser-sync'),
        reload     = brsync.reload;

var path = {
    dist:{
        html:'./dist/',
        css:'./dist/css/',
        js:'./dist/js/',
        img:'./dist/images/',
        font:'./dist/fonts/',
        lib:'./dist/libs/'
    },

    src:{
        html:'./src/*.html',
        css:'src/stylesheets/index.scss',
        js:'src/scripts/index.js',
        img:'src/images/**/*.*',
        font:'src/fonts/**/*.*',
        lib:'src/libs/**/*.*'
    },

    watch:{
        html:'./src/*.html',
        css:'src/sass/**/*.*',
        js:'src/js/**/*.*',
        img:'src/images/**/*.*',
        font:'src/fonts/**/*.*'
    },

    clean:'./dist/'
};

/*------------------------------------*\
        #config server
\*------------------------------------*/

var conf = {
    server:{
        baseDir:'./dist/'
    },
    tunnel:false,
    host:'localhost',
    port:8080,
    logPrefix:'-Это бизнес детка-'
};

/*------------------------------------*\
        #tasks
\*------------------------------------*/

// #server
gulp.task('server', function () {
        brsync(conf);
});

// #clean
gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
        rimraf(path.clean, cb);
});

// #html
gulp.task('html', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.html)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.html))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

// #js
gulp.task('js',function(){
    browserify(path.src.js, { debug: true })
        .transform(reactify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(msct())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

// #sass
gulp.task('style', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.css)
        .pipe(sass({
        }).on('error',sass.logError))
        .pipe(prsts({
                browsers: ['last 10 versions'],
                cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(msts())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.css))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

// #libs
gulp.task('libs',function(){
    gulp.src(path.src.lib)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.lib));
});

// #build
gulp.task('build', [
        'html',
        'style',
        'libs'
        // 'js'
]);

// #watch
gulp.task('watch', function(){
        gulp.watch(path.watch.html,['html']);
        gulp.watch(path.watch.css,['style']);
        gulp.watch(path.watch.js,['js']);
});

// #default
gulp.task('default', ['build', 'server', 'watch']);
```

При этом всё работает [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но папка dist не создаётся и пофакту вообще ничего не собирается.

Comment: Думаю, если бы вы сразу привели **минимальный** пример, иллюстрирующий проблему, получили бы ответ раньше ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто: функция, передаваемая в `gulp.task` **должна** возвращать файловый поток, обещание (promise) или вызывать функцию обратного вызова (см. [документацию](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support)). Без этого, асинхронные задачи не будут выполняться как положено, что вы и наблюдаете.

Приведу корректный код, одного из ваших заданий(остальные правятся по аналогии):

```
gulp.task('html', function () {
    return gulp.src(path.src.html)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.html))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```